# Software to clone / recover data from almost dead ssd on MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, ssd, recovery, data-recovery

MPB 15 2011 with Sierra on an ssd.

ssd is almost dead, Mac OS (Sierra) isn't loading with a folder with question mark showing on boot. The drive is detected in bios though, which gives me hope :)

I've taken it out of mac, connected to a regular pc & checked with mhdd & it shows dead & unrecoverable sectors on it.

Disk utility from mac internet recovery isn't showing any partitions on the drive & cannot make an image because of input/output error.

So I've googled & installed "Data Rescue 4" https://www.prosofteng.com/data-rescue-recovery-software on another MBP & made a bootable rescue usb to try to recover data, but this thing isn't working properly :(

Is there anything else I could use? I'd like to boot from smth which I can put on a usb with f.e. Rufus & either recover data to another usb hdd or make a sector by sector clone of an ssd drive with an option to skip dead/unreadable sectors to work on it on another machine.

Please recommend smth you tested & works well with Macs.

Thanks!

Comment: First thing to do would be imaging the drive with a proper tool (namely `ddrescue`, the GNU version of it) and then you can work on the image to restore it. Was Filevault enabled?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about ddrescue, it looks great! Not sure about Filevault being enabled as it's my friend's Mac. I'm creating an *.img file from the ssd now & later on plan to work on it with some other software.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to recover is to restore from your backup. Assuming you don't have a backup, you could try Disk Warrior, as I've found it tends to work well. Although damaged SSDs are trickier than hard drives, it may work.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a backup, otherwise I'd just throw this ssd out :) Will Disk Warrior work on an *.img file which I'm creating right now with ddrescue?

Comment: I’m not sure. They might mention it on their website. If not, they’ll probably tell you if you ask.

Answer (score -2):

You can also try [Stellar Mac Data Recovery](https://thesweetbits.com/best-data-recovery-software-mac-os/), another paid solution. I've used the latest version 7 with good results.